# Using linkname in includepdf

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, pdfpages

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\nameref{mypdflabel} on page~\ref{mypdflabel}

\newpage

\newcounter{inclPDFpage}
\includepdf[pages=-,link,linkname="This is the title I want",pagecommand={\refstepcounter{inclPDFpage}\label{mypdflabel}}]{mypdf.pdf}

\end{document}
```

The output of the above code is simply "on page 2" but I want it to show "This is the title I want on page 2", which is what I thought nameref would do.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: No, this is some kind of misunderstanding. `linkname` just changes the name of the hyper anchor, but not the title of the link itself. Also you're inserting the same label again since in case of there should be more than one page in your `mypdf.pdf`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`linkname` does not provide a name for a page etc, it changes only the hyper anchor name, e.g `linkname=foo` would give `foo.1` etc. where `1` is a page number.

The following example does provide the correct `\@currentlabelname` stored by `\label`, which is then extracted with `\nameref` later on, but please note that in case of having more than page in an included `.pdf` file, LaTeX will complain about multiple labels with the same name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\providename}[2]{%
  \edef\@currentlabelname{#1}%
  \label{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\nameref{mypdflabel} on page~\ref{mypdflabel}



\newpage

\newcounter{inclPDFpage}
\includepdf[pages=-,link,pagecommand={\refstepcounter{inclPDFpage}\providename{This is the title I want}{mypdflabel}}]{7.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @user31729 you're a genius! Saved my day, thank you very much..